# How to tell when Windows Update is finished

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, vbscript

In Windows 10 Home, the options for Windows Update are limited. I would like to stop it from starting up and instead have the user launch it when they are ready. The reason is that it starts too frequently, taking too long and it eats up the battery and the user is not happy.

I can disable the Window Update service and setup a reminder for the user to launch a script to re-enable it and start it up. But how do I tell when Windows Update has completed so I can re-disable the service again?

This question does not help...

[how-to-detect-quickly-that-windows-update-is-running-right-now-on-my-pc](https://superuser.com/questions/542969/)

Comment: **But how do I tell when Windows Update has completed so I can re-disable the service again?** - Updates to Windows are release on Tuesdays, a good time to restart, is after they have been released.  So you install the updates, reboot, and do all maintenance items at once.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok. If the updates require a restart I can setup a startup item to re-disable the service. But what if the updates do not require a reboot? How do I know when they finished installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you can schedule a PowerShell script  with Task Scheduler to check every Wednesday the Windows Update Client History.

I put a quick script that checks whether all updates applied within the last day have succeeded.

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"

$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$yesterday = (Get-Date).Addmonths(-5)

$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()



$Searcher = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Where-object {$_.Date -gt $yesterday} |Select-Object Title, Date,

    @{name="Result"; expression={switch($_.ResultCode){

       0{"NotStarted"}; 1 {"InProgress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"SucceededWithErrors"}; 4 {"Failed"}; 5{"Aborted"}

}}} 


if ($Searcher -eq $null){

Write-Host "Updates not found."
break

}

#Checks for whether all updates installed correctly.
if ($Searcher.Result -eq "Succeeded"){

Write-Host "Everything installed."

#Stops windows service
Stop-Service -Name wuauserv -Force
Get-service  -Name wuauserv 


}
elseif ($Searcher.Result -eq "InProgress"){

Write-Host "Updates are still been applied."
}
else {


Write-Host "Updates are in error status"
$Searcher 
}
```

NOTE:

Credit goes to Kurt Hudson and Peter Gleelen at the Microsoft TechNet Forum  for posting **[How to List All of the Windows and Software Updates Applied to a Computer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/) which allows to search for updates and also select which updates you would like to be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do: 
> • **Check
>   for updates** 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • Hiding unwanted updates
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • Configure Automatic Updates
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader

Comment: This is not open source, and considering how critical WU is to the security of the OS, no thank you.

Comment: this tool only calls WU API, I see no issue using it.This is the only tool I currently know that provides a deeper WU control on Windows 10. Use it or accept the default Windows 10 update mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the module PSWindowsUpdate from [PS Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate) you can just check for available updates after each patch run until there are no more...

```
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
```

```
while (Get-WUList) {
  Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
}
```

Now, you of course, need to start this after each reboot until there are no more patches.